# Mere presence of ES6 setters/getters causes performance hit in an unrelated function (V8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

1) Make an object and give it a simple method, e.g.,

```
let R = {
  f: (x) => Math.sqrt(x)
}
```

2) Benchmark its performance, e.g., call f(x) a few million times
3) Now add a getter, e.g.,

```
let R = {
  f: (x) => Math.sqrt(x),
  get h() {return 0}
}
```

4) Benchmark f(x) again. Performance in chrome/node (V8 engine) drops significantly.

Any explanations for this weirdness?

Here's a codepen snippet for this: https://codepen.io/iiroullin/pen/XWbwoVQ

**A work-around:**

It seems that defining the getters/setters the old (ES5) way does not break V8 optimization. So, while they are ironing out all kinks in ES6, instead of (3) one can use this:

```
Object.defineProperty(R, 'h', {get: () => 0})
```

and such for all getters/setters.

**Another fix:**

Use classes, see the answer below

Comment: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2015/11/performance-implication-object-defineproperty/

Comment: Aha! The issue described in the post you linked to seems quite similar. So good thing I am not alone in this misery :) Bad thing, the issue is still around 5 years later, unexplained...

Comment: It's the same thing: `Object.defineProperty`  is the ES5 way of doing getters. As  for why, I suspect that the indirection triggers a de-opt in the JIT. When you have a simple object with a pure method or two then they become inlined function calls. When you have an object with the indirection you pay for virtual method lookups. But that's just a guess. Hopefully a chrome engineer will pop up and answer the question definitively.

Comment: Investigating further along these lines, I stumbled upon a work-around: when I defined getters/setter via Object.defineProperty rather than directly, the performance loss disappeared. (So it looks like they did fix the issue from your link after all!) I guess the problem now must be that the V8 compiler optimization algorithm cannot handle ES6 definitions yet. (I'll add this finding to the post.)

Comment: Interesting. I'm a little surprised it's not the same mechanism under the hood, but then again C++ is sufficiently complicated that maybe it is and one still triggers the deopt but not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've filed a bug for this: [crbug.com/v8/10429](https://crbug.com/v8/10429)

Can you describe in what scenario (other than microbenchmarks) this comes up, in particular compared to defining getters on classes? The following seems to be fast:

```
class C {
  f(x) { return Math.sqrt(x); }
  get h() { return 0; }
}
let R = new C();

for (...) {
  R.f(...);
}
```

I suppose using classes for defining non-trivial objects is currently considered a "best practice"; if there are cases where classes don't fit the bill then that would be good to know so that engines can optimize for such patterns.

---

Side note @JaredSmith: The term "deopt" refers specifically to the situation of having to throw away optimized code when an assumption made at its compile time later on doesn't hold. That's not what's going on here.

Comment: I've re-written my code using classes and it works pretty good as well, and I like it! Perhaps it's time to change some programming habits...  ...I don't really know any specific scenario when defining accessors directly on an object via get/set (which would also have to be done at creation) would be preferable to using classes. In my case it was just a random thing cause lots of "old style habits" in JS programming :)

Comment: "*I suppose using classes for defining non-trivial objects is currently considered a "best practice"*" - I don't think using a `class` when only a single object is needed is considered a best practice. An object literal fits better, and should work just fine for non-trivial singletons as well.

Comment: After more tinkering, I recalled all the reasons why I never liked "classes" in JS. For example, in ES6, variables declared in the constructor are not accessible to the methods of the class, while all the class fields are public (privates are still experimental and not implemented in many engines). It's nice though that all engines are now able to optimize function calls through prototype chain so that calling a class function does not cost more than calling an instance function anymore. So while I am getting tempted, still, the "classes" in JS remain  mostly a gimmick to me ;)